Chime-React: How to show the EmptyVideoTile for remote users if camera is disable?
I am trying to achieve the below-mentioned functionality through chime-react-sdk:

For those who turn off the videos, EmptyVideoTile should appear for
the remote users.

I am trying to do that part with the UseAttendeeStatus hook. E.g: If the user videoEnabled is coming as a false then show the EmptyVideoTile but when any remote user disables the video from the remoteTileState The list also removes the tile for that user. How to handle that situation to show the EmptyVideoTile for all the remote users?
Any kind of help will be appreciated.
